# chrome extension to open in new tab instead of popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to get some data from current tab to my extension. It's working fine if I change it to popup style but I am looking for the same functionality to open it in a new tab on extension click. Can anybody guide on this how I can achieve this? Thanks in advance

***manifest.json.js***

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Hello World",
    "description": "A simple page-scraping extension for Chrome",
    "version": "1.0",
    "author": "@thomasforth",

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["popup.js"],
        "persistent": true
    },

    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "http://*/",
        "*://*/",
        "activeTab"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "logo.png"
        
    }
}
```

***payload.js***

```
// send the page title as a chrome message
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(document.title);
console.log(document.title)
```

***popup.js***

```
// Inject the payload.js script into the current tab after the popout has loaded
window.addEventListener('load', function (evt) {
    chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        file: 'payload.js'
    });;
});

// Listen to messages from the payload.js script and write to popout.html
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: "popup.html", selected: false })
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
    
    document.getElementById('pagetitle').innerHTML = message;
    
})
})
```

[image: This the is error which I am getting]

This the is error which I am getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the id of the `tab` where onClicked was triggered and pass it to popup script using its URL:

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
  chrome.tabs.create({
    url: `popup.html?tabId=` + tab.id,
    selected: false,
  });
});
```

// popup.js

```js
const tabId = +new URLSearchParams(location.search).get('tabId');
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
  file: 'payload.js'
});
```